# What if I use the epsilon definition of convergence incorrectly?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$

The sequence converges iff $\forall\epsilon >0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\forall n\geq N:|\frac{1}{N}-0|<\epsilon$

So, since we have our $N$: $N>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, the convergence is proven.

Now, what if we insert an other limit? Lets say $1$.

Then we would have to find an $N$ such that $|\frac{1}{N}-1|<\epsilon$.

We would get $N>\frac{1}{\epsilon +1}$

Does that mean that we have proven that $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to $1$?

Answer (score 3):

You've written the definition of convergence wrong: it should be $$\forall\epsilon >0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\forall n\geq N:|\frac{1}{n}-0|<\epsilon.$$ What you wrote was $$\forall\epsilon >0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\forall n\geq N:|\frac{1}{N}-0|<\epsilon,$$ which does not actually use "$n$" at all.

The point is that, in order to show that ${1\over n}\rightarrow L$, it's not enough to find an $N$ such that $\vert {1\over N}-L\vert<\epsilon$; you need to find some $N$ such that *for every $n>N$,* you have $\vert{1\over n}-L\vert<\epsilon$.

This matters, because for $L\not=0$ such an $N$ doesn't exist! For instance, you ask about taking $L=1$. Well, we *can* find an $N$ such that $\vert {1\over N}-1\vert$ is small - take $N=1$! Then no matter what $\epsilon>0$ we pick, $\vert {1\over N}-1\vert<\epsilon$. However, this doesn't work for $n>N$. To see this, take $\epsilon={1\over 2}$; then no matter what $N$ you pick, if I set $n=N+2$ then $$\vert {1\over n}-1\vert=\vert {1\over N+2}-1\vert=\vert -{N+1\over N+2}\vert={N+1\over N+2}\ge {2\over 3}>\epsilon.$$ So there is no $N$ such that *all $n$ greater than $N$* give values close to $1$, which is what convergence to $1$ would demand.